# combine two datasets by ID and Date

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

i want to combine two datasets that look like this:

| ID | Date | X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 01.01.2022 | 15 |
| 1235 | 02.01.2022 | 244 |

| ID | Date | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 01.01.2022 | 7 |
| 1235 | 04.01.2022 | 18 |

into one that looks like this

| ID | Date | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Number | dd.MM.YYYY | Number | Number |
| 1234 | 01.01.2022 | 15 | 7 |
| 1235 | 02.01.2022 | 244 | 0 |
| 1235 | 04.01.2022 | 0 | 18 |

Sometimes for a certain date, there might not be an X and a Y value

in the end, I need a table/chart that allows me to filter for one ID and gives me all the X and Y data for said ID depending on their dates (months).

I am really new to the whole Access thing and am learning by doing. Couldn't find a way to do this by Googling, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What data type are the two ID fields? Can be helpful to provide sample data as formatted text tables (not image).

Comment: Both are just Numbers. I hope the post is a bit clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [Use a union query to combine multiple queries into a single result](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-union-query-to-combine-multiple-queries-into-a-single-result-1f772ec0-cc73-474d-ab10-ad0a75541c6e?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361):

```sql
Select ID, [Date], X As X1, 0 As Y2 From Dataset1
Union All 
Select ID, [Date], 0 As X1, Y As Y2 From Dataset2
```

Save it as *DatasetU*.

Next, use this in an *aggregating* query:

```sql
Select 
    DatasetU.ID, 
    DatasetU.[Date], 
    Sum(DatasetU.X1) AS X, 
    Sum(DatasetU.Y2) AS Y
From 
    DatasetU
Group By 
    DatasetU.ID, 
    DatasetU.[Date]
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an option.

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Date, X, Y FROM Table2 
    RIGHT JOIN Table1 ON (Table2.Date = Table1.Date) AND (Table2.ID = Table1.ID)
UNION SELECT Table2.ID, Table2.Date, X, Y FROM Table1 
    RIGHT JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.Date = Table2.Date) AND (Table1.ID = Table2.ID);
```